# Unexpected behaviour of pre increment operator in C

Tags: c

```
   #include <stdio.h>
    void main()
    {
      int i = -3, j=2, k=0, m;
      m=  ++i|| ++j && ++k; 
      printf("%d%d%d%d", i, j, k, m);
    }
```

If we see order of evaluation in `++i|| ++j && ++k;` we will come up with evaluation of `++j && ++k` at first it will increment value of j and k and it will evaluate as 1 after that 
`++i || 1`  will evaluate which will increment value of i and assign 1 to m so output should be `-2 3 1 1` but it's giving output `-2 2 0 1` I think i am missing some concept here.

Comment: Why write code that is at best unreadable? If you have to scratch your head to understand if you are doing something wrong

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`||` and `&&` are short-circuiting operators. They don't evaluate the second operand if it is not necessary to determine the output.

Here, `++i` evaluates to a non-zero value, which is `true` in a boolean context. The right-hand side is not evaluated at all.

Comment: Here && operator has greater precedence then || operator so ++j && ++k it will evaluated first as && is binary operator so ++j will evaluated and since this is non-zero value that's why ++k will be evaluated. I might be wrong

Comment: Precedence and order of evaluation are unrelated. || and && are actually really special with their property of having a defined order of evaluation (left hand side first, right hand side only if necessary) and introduce a sequence point. The `?:` operator is another one with the same sort of characteristics. Otherwise order of evaluation is generally unspecified.

Comment: What I have understand In case of || and && operator we don't need to care about precedence Right? So  ++i|| ++j && ++k this will evaluate like ++i || (++j && ++k)

Comment: No. Precedence rules say && binds tighter than ||, so that expression is parsed as `++i || (++j && ++j)`. You really do need to care about that. But again, precendence rules are not "order of evaluation" rules.

Comment: So expression : ++i || (++j && ++k) expression (++j && ++k) will going to execute first ?

Comment: Nonononono. Please re-read my answer. The left hand side will be evaluated first, the right hand side will only be evaluated if the left hand side was false in this case. Again, || and && are special in this regard. You generally don't have any control at all over the order of evaluation - it's unspecified in general. Precedence does not determine order of evaluation in C or C++.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43898/discussion-between-nishant-and-mat)

Answer (score 3):

Since operator `||` and `&&` are short circuit evaluated, once `++i` is evaluated as `true`, `++j` and `++k` won't be evaluated. Thus, `j` and `k` are unchanged.

Answer (score 1):

**Logical operator always evaluates from left to right**. These operators are known as short-circuit operator, i.e, if the value of the expression can be deduced from the value of the left operand alone, then right operand is not evaluated. Since `i` is non zero here, `++j && ++k` is never evaluated and hence no modification is done to `j` and `k`.
**Operator precedence has nothing to do with the order of evaluation**. Do not get confused.

Answer (score 0):

m will be equal to 1 since first , the *OR* condition is first evaluated, and as ++i is non-zero, you will get

```
m=1
```

as the first part of the OR statement itself is *true*, second part is not evaluated. So your j and k values will remain *unchanged*.

Comment: && has greater predence than || then why the OR condition will be evaluated first ?